# how to change sprite of 2d object in unity during runtime?

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

I want to change the sprite of my 2d object from a blank box to a box with a 1 written on it upon clicking the box. how to I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the sprite ready, all you need to do is reference it in the script you're using.

So something like this:

```
public Sprite newSprite;
void Start () {
    gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite; 
    //this will immediately change your sprite to the new one
}
```

Also tested the code, it works. See the [SpriteRenderer reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) for more info on this component.

[image]

Comment: should i put the sprite in the resources folder?

Comment: Your sprite should be imported into unity (Assets folder or any other folder in the project) then you should drag the sprite onto the little box on the right. I'll add a picture to show what I mean.

Comment: yes i have them in my assets/resources folder then i just call them?

Comment: Also note that it is highly inefficient to call GetComponent() in Update(). The component reference should be cached to a variable in OnEnable() or Start().

Comment: You first make a reference to it in the editor or you get it from the assets by searching (referencing from the editor like in the picture is better for performance, but it could become a hassle if you like scripting instead of fiddling with the editor) and as @Lasse said, it's always best not to use GetComponent() in Update() for performance reasons.

Comment: it works! it assigns the sprite i want it to display. but how can i make it change in the middle of runtime? for example i have a green box then upon clicking it i want to change it to a red box. do i put the code you worte in my OnMouseDown code?